# Does scylla 4.4 supports python3.9?

Tags: python, python-3.x, scylla

I am trying to install scylla on the system I have python3.9.2, but received following error.

```
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 scylla-tools-core : Depends: python-yaml but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I have received this error after writing following command.

```
sudo apt install scylla
```

Comment: Packages in `apt` are arranged to generally work with each other, unless you've added a bunch of rogue PPAs. Have you done the usual apt debugging? `apt autoremove --purge && apt update && apt install -f`

Comment: What is the OS and OS version you are installing on?

Comment: I am using it on parrot OS, and I found on it's website that it doesn't support this OS, probably, this OS has no server version. If you can suggest a way to run it on this os, then it will be good otherwise it's ok. I have thought that most of the debian things run on parrot, so the os won't be a problem, but I was wrong.